# Is there a way to prevent Microsoft Word 365 from showing spelling suggestions on LEFT click?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

A (recent?) new behavior of Word that seems to have come with an update (presumably to make the application friendlier to users working on tablets and such, who may lack a right-click modality) is that spelling suggestions are now shown on *left click* (LMB / primary click) *in addition to* right click (RMB / context-click). The menu has a slightly different appearance between the two, because one is exclusive to spelling suggestions and the other also shows the standard context-menu options just with the spelling suggestions foldout pre-opened.

On (accidental) left click, we now have:

[image: Screenshot of Microsoft Word's new on-demand spellcheck menu that appears after left-clicking a word that is marked as misspelled]

On right click, we have the same as always:

[image: Screenshot of Microsoft Word's classic on-demand spellcheck menu that appears after right-clicking a word that is marked as misspelled]

Since I often take notes about programming or other arcane subjects using Word, this behavior is bothersome because things like `fnameescape()` will always wind up underlined, so it's very easy to accidentally click something Word has identified as misspelled when simply repositioning the typing cursor using the mouse. The red underlines don't *visually* bother me and are useful to retain for blocks of explanatory text so I'm not making misspellings within those.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior without shutting off active spellcheck entirely? I can uncheck **"Check spelling as you type"** in the **Proofing** section of the settings, but this disables spelling and grammar graphics entirely, and going through a document using the spellcheck dialog (F7) would be impractical because I want to ignore big parts of the document. Spell-checking only a selection at a time is also a poor choice because blocks of text may be highly interspersed with blocks of characters that are filled with "misspellings".

I pose this question as it pertains to the desktop version of Office-365 Word on Windows 10. The action-center (the speech-bubble on the taskbar which appears to the right of the clock) indicates that Tablet Mode is not active and I still see the behavior despite not having any stylus-devices plugged in. I'm open to VBA solutions or other tricks in case there's no explicit option to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The best I've figured out so far is that holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while left-clicking will prevent the LMB spelling-suggestions menu from appearing. This works, but isn't too optimal, as it requires remembering to do so, and hopefully remembering ***not*** to do so in other applications where this habit might cause problems.

Hopefully that at-least-slightly helps others in similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to roll back MSO version to the last one that came before the addition of this misconceived spelling menu. Here is how you can do that:

https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/uninstall-update-office-click-run/

The version I reverted to is compilation **16.0.13929.20296** (you might need a system restart for it to apply).

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a new Custom Dictionary with a few words:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/add-or-edit-words-in-a-spell-check-dictionary-56e5c373-29f8-4d11-baf6-87151725c0dc?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: Are you suggesting that I create a new dictionary with every Pascal/camel-cased function-name I've used in a given document?